# How to call a web service dynamically without add service reference over SSL

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, asmx

I'm developing a client that call a web service without add service reference. The method receives as a parameter an XML.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xmlAux = string.Empty;
        string link = "https://test.xxx.com/xxx/xxx.asmx";            
        
        string arg1 = @"<tuca> <hd>  <t_doc>10</t_doc> <id_user>xxx</id_user> <pwd>xxx</pwd> <id_pais>xxx</id_pais> </hd> <parametros> <par tipo=""tipo_sujeto"">fisico</par> <par tipo=""calificacion"">xxx</par> <par tipo=""CEDULA DE IDENTIDAD"">xxx</par> </parametros> </tuca>";

        object[] arguments = { arg1 };
        
        var ws = CallWebService(link, "xxx", "Reporte", arguments);
        
        if (ws != null)
        {
            xmlAux = ws.ToString();
        }
    }
     [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermissionAttribute(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Unrestricted = true)]
    internal static object CallWebService(string webServiceAsmxUrl, string serviceName, string methodName, object[] args)
    {
        System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();

        // Connect To the web service
        System.IO.Stream stream = client.OpenRead(webServiceAsmxUrl + "?wsdl");

        // Now read the WSDL file describing a service.
        var description = System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription.Read(stream);

        ///// LOAD THE DOM /////////
        // Initialize a service description importer.
        var importer = new System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescriptionImporter();

        importer.ProtocolName = "Soap12"; // Use SOAP 1.2.

        importer.AddServiceDescription(description, null, null);

        // Generate a proxy client.
        importer.Style = System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescriptionImportStyle.Client;

        // Generate properties to represent primitive values.
        importer.CodeGenerationOptions = System.Xml.Serialization.CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateProperties;

        // Initialize a Code-DOM tree into which we will import the service.
        var nmspace = new System.CodeDom.CodeNamespace();

        var unit1 = new System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit();
        unit1.Namespaces.Add(nmspace);

        // Import the service into the Code-DOM tree. This creates proxy code that uses the service.
        var warning = importer.Import(nmspace, unit1);

        if (warning == 0) // If zero then we are good to go
        {
            // Generate the proxy code
            var provider1 = System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

            // Compile the assembly proxy with the appropriate references
            string[] assemblyReferences = new string[5] { "System.dll", "System.Web.Services.dll", "System.Web.dll", "System.Xml.dll", "System.Data.dll" };

            var parms = new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters(assemblyReferences);

            var results = provider1.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parms, unit1);

            // Check For Errors
            if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerError oops in results.Errors)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("========Compiler error============");
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(oops.ErrorText);
                }

                throw new System.Exception("Compile Error Occured calling webservice. Check Debug ouput window.");

            }

            // Finally, Invoke the web service method
            object wsvcClass = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(serviceName);

            var mi = wsvcClass.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);

            return mi.Invoke(wsvcClass, args);

        }

        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

In the line:

```
return mi.Invoke(wsvcClass, args)
```

throws exception:

> InnerException: {"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."}
>
> Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: I have the same problem , only that i see is that if you invoke one service that do not have arguments it works , but with arguments it says: Parameter count does not match , you can research putting more arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with this post:

Invoking a Web Service dynamically using System.Net and SOAP

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/f9935e/invoking-a-web-service-dynamically-using-system-net-and-soap/